# Como REALIZAR UN AJAX A Datos sacados desde otro AJAX (*Update)

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, prepared-statements

Intento crear una "edición de categorías", mostradas en una tabla, y en la que al darle clic a "editar":

- Carga una petición AJAX, con los datos en un Modal, de la categoría seleccionada.
- Entonces, si modifico algún dato en estos input (sacados desde la petición ajax) al darle a "Actualizar" no me ocurre absolutamente nada.

-
ESTE ES EL PRIMER AJAX:

```
  $('.editar').click(function() {
    var idcat = $(this).attr('idcat');
    var action = "buscar-categoria";

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/api.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          idcat: idcat,
          action: action
        },
        success: function(e) {
          $('#cat-content').html(e);
          $('.modal').show();

        },
        error: function(e) {
          alert('fail');
        }
    });
  });
```

- Me saca varios INPUT, como he comentado, bien, ahora, al intentar hacer el siguiente AJAX, no sucede nada:

> ```
>   $('.editarcategoria').click(function() {
>     var idcat = $('#id_cat').val();
>     var nombre_categoria = $('#nombre_categoria').val();
>     var slash = $('#slash').val();
>     var url_cat = $('#url_cat').val();
>     var cat_destacada = $('#cat_destacada').val();
>     var action = "editar-categoria";
>
>     $.ajax({
>         url: 'php/api.php',
>         type: 'POST',
>         data: {
>           idcat: idcat,
>           nombre_categoria: nombre_categoria,
>           slash: slash,
>           url_cat: url_cat,
>           cat_destacada: cat_destacada,
>           action: action
>         },
>         success: function(e) {
>           $('.modal').hide();
>           alert(e);
>
>         },
>         error: function(e) {
>           alert('fail');
>         }
>     });
>   });
> ```

Voy a añadir el PHP de este último AJAX:

> ```
>   function editarCategoria() {
>
>     $con = getConn();
>
>     $idcat = $_POST['idcat'];
>     $nombre_categoria = $_POST['nombre_categoria'];
>     $slash = $_POST['slash'];
>     $url_cat = $_POST['url_cat'];
>     $cat_destacada = $_POST['cat_destacada'];
>
>     $query = 'UPDATE bt_categorias SET nombre = ?, slash = ?, url = ?, destacada = ? WHERE id_categoria = ?';
>
>     if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
>         $stmt->bind_param("sssii", $nombre_categoria, $slash, $url_cat, $cat_destacada, $idcat);
>         $stmt->execute();
>
>         $resultado = 'Filas Afectadas: '.$stmt->affected_rows;
>
>         $stmt->close();
>     }
>
>
>     return $resultado;
>   }
> ```

¿Alguna sugerencia o forma de poder realizar este tipo de acciones?
Muchas gracias a todos de ante mano.

Javier.

Comment: Intenta con `$(document).on('click', '.editarcategoria', function() {`

Comment: Me acaba de funcionar, sin embargo, me dice que Filas Afectadas: 0, creo que al haber cargado esos datos por ajax, no los lee al hacerle el .val()

Comment: Listo, se me pasó una cosita al haber cambiado eso, ¡Ahora si funciona!! Menuda tontuna de error! mil gracias!!!